# Django Site encryption

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am writing a site for which I require all data to be transmitted under encryption.

Last night I was considering encrypting form data before posting it but I've just created a Django form for login and realised that using the action field will send the data back to the server unencrypted.

```
<form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div id="login_box_user">{{loginForm.userName}}</div>
            <div id="login_box_pass">{{loginForm.password}}</div>
            <div id="login_box_sbmt"><input id="submitbutton" name="submit" value="Login" type="submit" /></div>
        </form>
```

I'm thinking that in order to get around this, I would need to have a Javascript function as the action to encode it before sending, or a Javascript submit button.

At the same time I'm thinking about SSL but we don't currently have a server running so I wouldn't be able to connect an SSL certificate to it for use during development/testing.
The way I understand it, using SSL the data transmitted would be encrypted. I'm wondering if it is worth the effort of encrypting everything, when I plan to get an SSL certificate and using SSL once we have a domain for the site

Answer (score 6):

Encryption in JavaScript is useless as [explained here](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/). So SSL is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some information here if you plan to deploy your site with https:

http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2009/02/18/securing-django-with-ssl/